# Error installation custom django app package

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to install in a Django project my own package but when add the app to `INSTALLED_APPS` through the next error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django_dashboards_app'

[Code](https://gitlab.com/albertosanmartinmartinez/django-dashboards)
[pypi](https://pypi.org/project/django-dashboards-app/)

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by moving the files to a folder with the same name inside the package folder.